# Karate update 1.1.0 changing a background connection with the java runner file

Tags: java, karate

New engineer here, upon updating to 1.1.0, from 1.0.1 some of the test suite broke, it stopped working on RC3 and later. The background of these tests are calling the java file to create a map and populate it with testData used in the test, but after the update the maps are created but null. After reading the manual and Q&A's, I'm was wondering if my predecessor set this method up in a way that was unsupported approach and if so is a simple method for this that you would recommend instead.

the offending background:

```
@parallel=false
Feature: Tests to verify response from Detector Set API

  Background:
    # Get api url from karate-config.js
    * url baseUrl
    # This configures the http headers to use admin user for running the tests
    * callonce read('classpath:common/headers/admin-headers.feature')
    * def DetectorSetControllerTest = Java.type('apitests.application.riskdetectors.detectorset.DetectorSetControllerApiTest')
    * def testData = DetectorSetControllerTest.detectorSetTestDataMap
```

The Java code it is calling:

```
public static Map<String, Object> detectorSetTestDataMap = null;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void testData() {
        detectorSetTestDataMap = Runner.runFeature(DetectorsCommon.class,
                "testdata/create-detectorset-test-data.feature",
                null,
                true);
    }
```

Thank you for your work.

Comment: please go through the upgrade guide: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue